# Create Word document based on multiple items from a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, word-automation

I've done some research and I know it's possible to create a Word document out of data from an item in a list.

So, before asking the question, I'll describe de scenario. Every month departments A, B and C needs to generate a report that will be used to make an executive summary, the problem is that these reports are not standardized -no matter how many times department A, B and C has been told to use a standardized template-.

The idea that comes to mind, is to create a list so that users are forced to input the data in a form.

Example:

Item, Year, Month, Department, NoteX, NoteY, NoteZ

1, 2016, 12, A, Notes, Notes, Notes

2, 2016, 12, B, Notes, Notes, Notes

Is it possible that I can generate a word document of this sort by using the data available?

### Year 2016, Month 12.

### Department A:

- notes
- notes
- notes

### Department B:

- notes
- notes
- notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while of looking into this, I ended up exporting the information from the list into an Excel file (Default), by using formulas (Fill month and year for the report) I would populate sections out of the connection from Sharepoint and then copy/paste it to a Word Document.

Yes I know, it's not automated creation of reports into a word file, but it definitely did the trick using OOTB functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called a mail merge. There are several ways to do this. Two examples are the following.

You can use SharePoint Designer to solve the problem.

[Automatically create Word documents which include list fields](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/brenclarke/2009/04/15/automatically-create-word-documents-which-include-list-fields/)

OR

Use an Add-In

[SharePoint Document Merge (List Data to Templates)](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&assetid=WA104379659&appredirect=false)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I haven't said anything yet cause I need a more in depth look but the first link at least I've already seen and it only works for a single item initially.

Comment: The problem is that you are using SharePoint online, so you can't use a custom coded solution, which would be ideal for this type of need.